# Can I use a persistent (Oracle) recordset in access project?

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset, persistent

Obviously you cannot set the `recordset` property of a form in an `Access Project` with an `Oracle-based recordse`t, but is there a way to show or select these records in an `Access form`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a DSN entry for the Oracle database in the ODBC control panel
2. In Access, create a new Query, define it as Pass-Through, type whatever you want in the query text otherwise you can't save it (**SELECT *** is ok). This pass-trough query will be used to retrieve data from Oracle and show them in your form, and you will define it's SQL on-the-fly in the VBA code
3. In your form code, do this:

---

```
' Add this local variable to your form
Private OracleQD As QueryDef   

' Do the following in the Load event of your form :
Set OracleQD = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Your_Previously_Created_Query_name")   
OracleQD.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=your_ODBC_entry_name;UID=your_Oracle_User;Pwd=Your_Oracle_Password"
OracleQD.ODBCTimeout = 600  ' Set to anything you want

' Do this everytime you want to retrieve data from Oracle
OracleQD.SQL = "SELECT * FROM whatever_table_you_want"
Set Form_Your_form_name.Recordset = OracleQD.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
```

---

Comment: This would work for an access mdb databse but not for an access project (.adp). I tried this approach but setting the recordset of a form only works if it is based on a sql server table, view or stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a table on the back-end server, looping through the oracle-based recordset in VBA and then creating new records in the (sql server) table by using a stored procedure which takes fields from the oracle-based recordset as parameters and inserts these values as a record in the sql server table.